# Glue Job Succeeded but no data inserted into the target table (Aurora Mysql)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-aurora, aws-glue-data-catalog

I created a glue job using the visual tab like below. First I connected to a mysql table as data source which is already in my data catalog. Then in the transform node, I wrote a custom sql query to select only one column from the source table. Validated with the data preview feature and the transformation node works fine. Now I want to write the data to the existing database table that has only one column with 'string' data type. Glue job succeeded but I dont see the data in the table.

[image]
**Below is the automatic script generated from Glue Job Visual.**

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame


def sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query, mapping, transformation_ctx) -> DynamicFrame:
    for alias, frame in mapping.items():
        frame.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(alias)
    result = spark.sql(query)
    return DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glueContext, transformation_ctx)


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node MySQL
MySQL_node1650299412376 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="glue_rds_test",
    table_name="test_customer",
    transformation_ctx="MySQL_node1650299412376",
)

# Script generated for node SQL
SqlQuery0 = """
select CUST_CODE from customer
"""
SQL_node1650302847690 = sparkSqlQuery(
    glueContext,
    query=SqlQuery0,
    mapping={"customer": MySQL_node1650299412376},
    transformation_ctx="SQL_node1650302847690",
)

# Script generated for node MySQL
MySQL_node1650304163076 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=SQL_node1650302847690,
    database="glue_rds_test",
    table_name="test_customer2",
    transformation_ctx="MySQL_node1650304163076",
)

job.commit()
```

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing the exact same issue

Comment: thanks for mentioning the data preview feature - didn't know this beforehand

Answer (score 0):

For [me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631411/glue-job-succeeded-but-no-data-inserted-into-the-target-bucket) the problem was the double-quotes of the selected fields in the SQL query. Dropping the use of double quotes solved it. There is no mention of it in the [Spark SQL Syntax documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html)

For example, I "wrongly" used this query syntax:

```
select "CUST_CODE" from customer
```

instead of this "correct" one :

```
select CUST_CODE from customer
```

Your shared sample code does not seem to have this syntax issue, but I thought putting the answer here might be of a help to others.